# Finding subseries from an infinite INPUT of letters

Tags: python

You must assume that the input will be infinite, and you cannot put it into an array.

The program should return 3 types of subseries:

1. Every series starting with a and ending with b.
   For example, for :"acbabcba"
   The returned value will be 5
2. Every series starting with a and ending with b,
   which does not include c.
   For example, for :"acbabcba"
   The returned value will be 1
3. Every series starting with a and ending with b,
   which includes only one c.
   For example, for :"acbabcba"
   The returned value will be 3

```
def find_series():
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
    count3 = 0
    count_c = 0
    sum1 = 0
    sum2 = 0
    sum3 = 0
    latter = ""
    while latter != ".":
        latter = input("please enter your latter: ")
        if latter == "a" and count_c > -2:
            count3 += 1
        if latter == "a":
            count1 += 1
        if latter == "c":
            count_c -= 1
            count1 -= 1
        if latter == "b" and count_c == -1:
            sum3 += count3
            count_c = 0
        if latter == "b":
            sum1 += count1
        if latter == "b" and count_c == 0:
            sum2 += count2
    return sum1, sum2, sum3
```

This is the code I tried,
And I'm having trouble completing the third section.

If someone could help me get a new way of thinking about this question, I would be very happy.

Two facts should be noted: I am a beginner programmer,
And I tried to look for this question in the forum and I couldn't find it.